# Fetching TypeORM data with limit and order by and child relationship with getMany()

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I need a help with **nestjs** **typeorm** query. Scenario is as follows
Suppose i have 3 tables say Teachers, Students and Parents

1. Teachers = One to many relation w.r.t Students , i.e one teacher can
   teach multiple students.
2. Students = Many to one relation w.r.t
   Teachers.
3. Students = One to Many w.r.t Parents , assuming 1 child
   of Parents
4. Parents = Many to One w.r.t Students

```
    const records = await this.createQueryBuilder('teachers').leftJoinAndSelect('teachers.students', 'students').leftJoinAndSelect('students.parents', 'parents').orderBy('teachers.id', 'DESC').limit(1);
    let res = await records.getMany();
```

output something like this

```
{
  teacher_id: '4',
  teacher_name: 'abc',
  students: [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'pqr',
      status: 'failed',
      parents: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'mom',
          relationship: 'mom'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'dad',
          relationship: 'dad'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us say there are 100 teachers. Each teacher has 20 students and each student has 2 parents.

Total records which the query would return = 100 * 20 * 2 = 4000

But while showing the results in a paginated way we need to group records by `teacher.id`.

Total count using group by `teacher.id` = 100

Example code -

```
  async getTeacher(): Promise<any[]> {
      return await this.repo
      .createQueryBuilder('teachers')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('teachers.students', 'students')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('students.parents', 'parents')
      .groupBy('teachers.id')
      .orderBy('teachers.id','DESC')
      .limit(1)
      .getMany();
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm not looking for pagination, i'm looking for just 1 particular record ( limit 1 ), i have few condition like teacher name and student as failed, so 1 be 1 i need to show.

Comment: @KhushalChheda, glad to help you! I have updated the code as per your requirement. Thanks!

Comment: With this if you would check it gives 1 parent as output and not 2 . Similar query i have written if you would check that

Comment: @KhushalChheda, I request to use `getRawMany` instead of `getMany` and check if you are getting multiple records of parent